# How to search and sort by multiple filter fields in ASP.Net core 2.0 MVC using mysql database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

## How to Search based on Multiple Filter fields in ASP.Net core MVC.

I want to search the data across the MySQL database and then filter searched data with multiple filters in windows visual studio 2017.

## Model class

```
namespace i.model
{
public class CompanyRecords
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public int? user_id { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string modules { get; set; }
}
[enter image description here][1]}
```

## Context Model

```
 public List<CompanyRecords> GetProducts(string data,string idd, SearchModel searchSch)
    {   using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            List<CompanyRecords> results = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%" + data + "%' OR Keywords LIKE '%" + data + "%' OR product_name LIKE '%" + data + "%' OR description LIKE '%" + data + "%' OR modules LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR metatags LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR geographical_focus LIKE '%" + data + "%'").ToList();

            //if (idd == "Category")
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchSch.category))
            {
                //List<CompanyRecords> result = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%" + data + "%'").ToList();


               List<CompanyRecords> result = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>(results.Where(x=>x.category.Contains(searchSch.category))).ToList();

                return result;
            }
            else if (idd == "Keywords")
            {
                List<CompanyRecords> result = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>("SELECT * FROM product WHERE Keywords LIKE '%" + data + "%'").ToList();
                return result;
            }
            else if (idd == "Modules") {
                List<CompanyRecords> result = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>("SELECT * FROM product WHERE modules LIKE '%" + data + "%'").ToList();
                return result;
            }
            return results;         
            //List<CompanyRecords> results = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR description LIKE '%" + data + "%' OR modules LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR metatags LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR geographical_focus LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR target_job_titles LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR target_industry_type LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR desktop_web_both LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR dept_user_type LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR semantic LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR cognitive LIKE '%" + data + "%'OR target_campany_size LIKE '%" + data + "%'").ToList();
            //if (results != null)
            //{ return results; }
            //return results;
        }  
    }
```

Hear 
conn.Open();
            List results = conn.Query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%" + data + "%' OR Keywords LIKE '......).ToList();  gives the correct result Now I want to filter the Searched data that is result with Multiple filters like category,modules keywords etc...

Comment: Do you want to add an AND Statement to your SQL WHERE clauses or do you want to search in the c# code afterwards? You could search through a c# list using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries

Comment: I just want to search data using search string and filter the search result by multiple constraints .. for example, if I search property in particular area and whatever result from that result I want to filter by price type availability etc

Comment: WHERE is the filter statement in your sql... Maybe you mean ordering and not filtering?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think the main problem is your lack on english skills. Maybe you should try to find a translator or ask a question somewhere, where you can use your mother tongue.

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchSch.category))
            {
                //List<CompanyRecords> result = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%" + data + "%'").ToList();


               List<CompanyRecords> result = conn.Query<CompanyRecords>(results.Where(x=>x.category.Contains(searchSch.category))).ToList();

                return result;
            } ... This is the filter statment